# css aligning dynamically created checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a checkbox like this:http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/18/

Trying to get the new checkbox to appear to the right of the jpg and not below but for whatever reason I can't get it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkMain1" value="Main1" id="Main1" /><label for="Main1"><b>Main1</b></label>
<div id="holder">
    <a class="imgreport" href="images/pic.jpg"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/reports/thumb.png" alt=""/></a>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="chkMain2" value="Main2" id="Main2"><label for="Main2"><b> Main2</b></label>
<div id="holder">
        <a class="imgreport" href="images/pic.jpg"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/reports/thumb.png" alt=""/></a>
    </div>

<input type="checkbox" name="chkMain3" value="Main3" id="Main3"><label for="Main3"><b> Main3</b></label>
<div id="holder">
        <a class="imgreport" href="images/pic.jpg"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/reports/thumb.png" alt=""/></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: "holder" can be put in a seperate div with the pic in another if thats easier. As long as its to the right of the jpg.

Comment: The code in the question looks nothing like the code in the demo.

Comment: Fixed. The demo is showing the dropdown. "holder" is the same id where the checkbox is being populated.

Comment: can you add the styles for the class `.imgreport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `display` property like this:

```
.holder div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Check the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/22/

Or just don't append a `<div>` element because they are `block` for default pushing other elements up or down:

```
$(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<span>'+ctrl+lbl+'</span>');
```

Another Demo http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/23/

Comment: still populating below the jpg. edit to your edit: span worked, thanks.

Comment: @user3191137 can you add the styles for the class `.imgreport`